# EF Core 7 query performance when using TPC with multiple child tables

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a set of business objects that consist of a main object with some properties and a number of child components that are added to the `List<BaseComponent>` in the MainObject (MO).
BaseComponent is abstract and defines some common properties. Components inherit and also define own properties that are very different from one component to next. About 30 different components exist and which are added to which MO is arbitrary.

For persistence I use EF Core 7 (SqlServer) and TPC (Table-Per-Concrete-Type) approach so that each component child is stored in its own table and has an FK to the main table row.
Simple enough, so far so good.  Persistence layer works, Ef Core picks up and materializes MOs  with correct components in the List and so on.

My concern here is the innerworkings of the query mechanism, I'm not a database expert, I do have some knowledge of relational databases and SQL in general, but I can't for the life of me figure out how EfCore queries the child tables to only pickup components that belongs to a specific MO (efficiently that is).

Suppose I have a MO, I add five components and save it. MO is saved to its table and components to each their own tables using FK to refer to that MO row.
But the MO row does not contain any information about which components it has, components on the other hand have a FK column with MO row ID.

Does EF Core have to query all 30 component tables to find component rows that refer to a specific MO row ?  Or how does it find correct ones ?

My projected growth is circa 1 million MO row/year with any number of child components, I don't know how this will impact the performance of the data layer

Comment: Examine generated SQL. I do not see your code, model to give more detailed answer.

Comment: *"Does EF Core have to query all 30 component tables to find component rows that refer to a specific MO row ?"* Yes, that's how TPC relational database model works.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Isn't the term TPC enough, not sure what concrete model/code you need to give "more detailed answer".  TPC is basically everything in separate tables, UNION ALL queries etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev, probably you are right, I cannot think about complexity without code.

Comment: [TPC query performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#tpc-query-performance)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  - thank you,  this I have not seen (although I was reading docs). This answers a lot of my questions, specifically that about Union All subselects.

Use case is also justified so I am happy with the information you have give me,  Thanks !

Comment: Base tabe (in your case Main Object) has PK and shared properties. Child tables will have FK to main table, so yes, when querying main table EF Core will search for records in all child tables, which (if I remember correctly) will create a query with N `LEFT JOIN` clauses (where `N` is the amount of child tables). TPT is recommended only for legacy databases or special cases [quote](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-preview5/#:~:text=Use%20TPT%20only%20if%20constrained%20to%20do%20so%20by%20external%20factors.).

Comment: Exactly,  I confirmed that by observing SQL queries generated by EF.  They are rather complicated and now I will also implement search and query of type "give-me-all-main-objects-where-child-object-of-type-x-have-y-property-which-contains-value-z"